# Facebook module is no longer 64 bit in appcelerator 5.2GA

Tags: facebook, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

The Facebook module has stopped working. I am working on a tituanium app in appcelerator.

When I try to build my app, I get the following error:

```
[INFO] : Invoking xcodebuild
[ERROR] : * BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] : The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] : Ld build/Intermediates/Game.build/Debug-iphoneos/Game.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Game normal armv7
[ERROR] : Ld build/Intermediates/Game.build/Debug-iphoneos/Game.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Game normal arm64
[ERROR] : (2 failures)
```

I managed the to isolate the problem with the Facebook module, it is no longer 64 bit. How can I resolve this? This was working fine before the latest update.

Comment: It looks like you've found a bug. Stack Overflow is [not the right place](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) to report bugs. Please check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new version of ti.facebook iOS was released just today and can be downloaded here: https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.facebook/releases/tag/ios-5.1.0

The error was not related to the arch's, but to the `UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey` constant that was only iOS 9 and so not working with Xcode < 7. That is now fixed as well. Thanks!

Comment: Wish this has been done sooner - I ended up upgrading my operating system just so that I could update xcode, thanks though - sure it will help others.

Comment: Sorry, understand that. But as you may now, there are many critical fixes that need to be placed in time.

Answer (score 0):

If needed, you can download previous version of Facebook module here : https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.facebook/releases

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error and tho is the log of the build where  the error is evident...

anD I also tried version 5.0.0 of the pluGin agaIn whit no luck

[TRACE]  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
[TRACE]    "_UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey", referenced from:
[TRACE]        -[FacebookModule handleRelaunch] in libfacebook.a(FacebookModule.o)
[TRACE]  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
[TRACE]  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[ERROR]  ** BUILD FAILED **

please dOnT erase this responSe

Comment: this is better left as a comment, or a separate question if it differs enough from this one