# Appcelerator Titanium Facebook module is not working on some iOS devices

Tags: ios, facebook, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I made an application which requires logging with Facebook (via Facebook Module).

Application fulfilled test requirements and is distributed via Google Play and AppStore. During tests I had no problems with logging in via Facebook. Same with AppStore version.

I show Facbook authorization window after pressing pressing logging button which fires:

`myApp.fb.authorize();`

I did all the steps described in documentation (including `initialize()` etc) and it works on test devices and when I download it from AppStore.

Problem is that I have feedback from many iOS users (and video proof) that this Facebook authorization window does not show up on many iOS devices (user click the button and nothing happend). I couldn't find any reason for this because it affects:
 - different version of iOS,
 - different devices.
with no particular connection.

I have no device which have same problem so I cannot test and check what causes the error.

Does anyone encountered such problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Interestingly I got the same problem some days ago. My test devices work great but two iphones won't show the login box. I guessed it was a strange combination of 'blocked apps on fb' and apple fb settings. I don't have the phones to check either but I'll follow your question to see if someone can fix it

Comment: do you have the latest FB app installed on the devices that produce the error? Or if you update your device to the latest FB app does it still work?

Comment: @miga: 
On iOS there should be no difference if you have FB app or not because every app works in its 'sandbox'.

Comment: I am also having the same issues. The facebook login was working 2 days ago but today its not working. Did you find any fix for it .?

Comment: @Hasnain: If you have device with such problem please debug to check what is exact cause. It would help us all. As I wrote I don't have any device with such problem so I cannot hunt this error but this error occurs because a lot of my users have this problem.

Comment: @kreatywny I tried debugging as well on device. The strange thing is I have device with iOS 8 and facebook module 5.0.1 is working on it. This module comes as default with 5.2.2 SDK.

Next I tried with iOS 9 and its not working. SO I guess something is fishy with module.

Comment: @kreatywny what facebook module version are you using and what is your appcelerator SDK version.?

Comment: @Hasnain: By debugging I mean running app from Appcelerator Studio via USB. If you run app this way all the errors are shown in console. Do you get any information in console when u click button on iOS 9? I would expect some error message there.
I work with 5.2.2GA and I use the latest module (so it is 5.0.1).

Comment: @Hasain: It seems that error was in module. But I don't know if it was causing our error, because I got such error on different devices. Check this topic [Facebook module is no longer 64 bit in appcelerator 5.2GA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35866021/facebook-module-is-no-longer-64-bit-in-appcelerator-5-2ga?rq=1)

Comment: @kreatywny It seems there is some issues with the module. I used this module ios-5.2.0 (https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.facebook/releases) and it seems to be working without any issue in device. But its using safari for login not native facebook app. The default module with 5.2.2GA use native app.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the latest releases, it's worked
[Release Facebook Module](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.facebook/releases)