# Couldn't find module: facebook for architecture: x86_64

Tags: mobile, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

Yesterday i installed facebook module for my appcelerator titanium app, it worked perfectly on simulator and device.
When i launch simulator this morning, i receive this message : **Couldn't find module: facebook for architecture: x86_64** 
Do you have an idea of this bug please? on my tiapp xml i have :

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ti:app xmlns:ti="http://ti.appcelerator.org">
    <id>com.fbtest.fr</id>
    <name>fbtest</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <publisher>esy</publisher>
    <url>http://www.fbtest.fr</url>
    <description>undefined</description>
    <copyright>2016 by xxx</copyright>
    <icon>appicon.png</icon>
    <fullscreen>false</fullscreen>
    <navbar-hidden>false</navbar-hidden>
    <analytics>true</analytics>
    <guid>a7e1628d-e202-47a5-9ccc-c6f868dc3862</guid>
    <property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">dp</property>
    <property name="ti.facebook.appid">222219821644449</property>
    <ios>
        <enable-launch-screen-storyboard>true</enable-launch-screen-storyboard>
        <plist>
            <dict>
                <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~iphone</key>
                <array>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
                </array>
                <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
                <array>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
                </array>
                <key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key>
                <false/>
                <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
                <false/>
                <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
                <false/>
                <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
                <string>UIStatusBarStyleDefault</string>
                <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
                <array>
                    <dict>
                        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
                        <!-- Application ID same as the id value in the tiapp.xml file -->
                        <string>222219821644449</string>
                        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                        <array>
                            <!-- Prefix the Facebook App ID with 'fb' -->
                            <string>fb222219821644449</string>
                        </array>
                    </dict>
                </array>
                <key>FacebookAppID</key>
                <!-- Facebook App ID -->
                <string>222219821644449</string>
                <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
                <!-- Facebook App Name from developer.facebook.com -->
                <string>myappmobile</string>
                <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
                <!-- If dialog -->
                <array>
                    <string>fbapi</string>
                    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
                    <string>fbauth2</string>
                    <string>fbshareextension</string>
                </array>
                <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>facebook.com</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key> <true/>        
                    <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key> <false/>
                </dict>
            <key>fbcdn.net</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key> <true/>
                    <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>  <false/>
                </dict>
            <key>akamaihd.net</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key> <true/>
                    <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key> <false/>
                </dict>
        </dict>
</dict>
            </dict>
        </plist>
    </ios>
    <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
    <mobileweb>
        <precache/>
        <splash>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <inline-css-images>true</inline-css-images>
        </splash>
        <theme>default</theme>
    </mobileweb>
    <modules>
        <module platform="iphone">facebook</module>
        <module platform="android">facebook</module>
    </modules>
    <deployment-targets>
        <target device="android">true</target>
        <target device="ipad">false</target>
        <target device="iphone">true</target>
        <target device="mobileweb">false</target>
        <target device="windows">false</target>
    </deployment-targets>
    <sdk-version>5.2.2.GA</sdk-version>
    <plugins>
        <plugin version="1.0">ti.alloy</plugin>
    </plugins>
    <property name="appc-app-id" type="string">574fe360cdc3903902cd</property>
</ti:app>
```

Have i missed something ?

Comment: what is your facebook module version and if you build in iOS what is xcodebuilder version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are using 64 bit device now. If you are using outdated module then you need to use the latest one. If its the latest one then you may need to update your xcode. For Appcelerator in general its recommended to use everything updated.

You can find a bit more info here: [Facebook module is no longer 64 bit in appcelerator 5.2GA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35866021/facebook-module-is-no-longer-64-bit-in-appcelerator-5-2ga)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue when I updated my Xcode. I've spend hours to clear this issue and I finally found that my certificates were not set. So I choose the provisional profile for development and worked perfectly. Make sure your certificates are correctly selected.